# Install ROM to save android samsung galaxy mini GT-S5570

Tags: root-access, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-mini

I rooted this device about a year ago and attempted to install a rom however as I failed to find that much information on how to do it I ended up going into the stock recovery mode and attempting to install a zip file I had downloaded. I did this by choosing "apply update from sdcard".

Obviously this is completely wrong and my phone is now always stuck in a bootloop. It also seems I have filled up the entire memory of bogus files as when I tested to install a file through recovery mode I get the error "No space left on device".

My question is if there is any way I can install some ROM(or anything) so that I can use this phone again. It seems I can't do this through the phone as I don't have a custom recovery so if I can do anything from my mac that would be great.

I have also tried using heimdall-one-click to unbrick however it could not identify my device.

Comment: Can you boot into fastboot mode?

Comment: When I follow instructions for fastboot mode white text appears on my screen it does however not show android logo as the tutorial I followed said it would.

Comment: What does the text say?

Comment: First it says something like lcd_backlight_ctrl start. It mentions something about re-check normal boot and a little kernel.